# How do I terminate the Xserver

Tags: server, xorg

I just installed Ubuntu server 12.04 x86 on a virtual device (I'm using VirtualBox) and I executed the following commands: `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg` and `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` and it works fine, but I am a beginner and do not know how to terminate Xserver. (Terminate it, not just pressing `ctrl + alt + f1` to use the command line) Can you help me with that? I was doing some googleing and found a command : `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop` but it says it can't find the command. Any other ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After switching to another tty (ctrl + alt + f1), run

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

Ubuntu uses lightdm instead of gdm now.